# Kong API is returning 404 after configuring a service

Tags: java, spring, kong

I set up a Kong using docker and it was running fine. I configured a local service with the following info;

```
{
    "host": "localhost",
    "created_at": 1534727577,
    "connect_timeout": 60000,
    "id": "cc3a858f-09fc-4baa-a206-3bd5ad3f514a",
    "protocol": "http",
    "name": "iwc_client_management",
    "read_timeout": 60000,
    "port": 9007,
    "path": "/rfg/iwconnect/1.0",
    "updated_at": 1534727577,
    "retries": 5,
    "write_timeout": 60000
}
```

I also created a route for this service with the following info;

```
{
    "created_at": 1534727699,
    "strip_path": true,
    "hosts": [
        "iwconnect.com"
    ],
    "preserve_host": false,
    "regex_priority": 0,
    "updated_at": 1534727699,
    "paths": [
        "/clients"
    ],
    "service": {
        "id": "cc3a858f-09fc-4baa-a206-3bd5ad3f514a"
    },
    "methods": null,
    "protocols": [
        "http",
        "https"
    ],
    "id": "67c32503-e5d1-4aae-982b-bfa03a36582e"
}
```

According to this example,

[Let's go through a few examples](https://docs.konghq.com/0.14.x/proxy/). Consider a Route configured like this:

```
{
    "hosts": ["iwconnect.com"],
    "paths": ["/clients],
    "methods": ["GET"]
}
```

As per the Kong Document the following call will take effect;

*GET http://localhost:8000/clients
   header:
   Host : iwconnect.com*

but the response is:

```
error_404

{
    "message": "no route and no API found with those values"
}
```

Is there anything I missed or wrong configuration?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I used the same config you have done and Kong version 0.14 is working fine with that configuration. I am able to get the results for the call with /clients request.

Please check kong error logs under /usr/local/kong/logs/error.log and see what error you are getting. Error will also give you an idea if something is missing.